# Populate dataset from txt file

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, c#-datatable

Hi i've want to create a dataset and populate it with a txt file that i've with all italian names, for example:
abaco

abbondanza

abbondanzia

abbondanzio

abbondazio

abbondia

abbondina

Without spaces. Is there a simple code to do it? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] inputs = {"abaco","abbondanza","abbondanzia","abbondanzio","abbondazio","abbondia","abbondina"};
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Italian Names", typeof(string));

            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new string[] { input });
            }

 

        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE

```
  try
            {
                // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
                // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Fabio\\Desktop\\dataset\\nomi_italiani.txt"))
                {
                    string line;
                    // Read and display lines from the file until the end of
                    // the file is reached.
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                       listnamedataset = //HOW CAN I ADD EVERY ELEMENT TO THE LIST??

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
 
            }
```

Comment: no.... in inputs i don't only have theese names.... i've 4k names into a file...

Comment: So modify code to read the names from file using StreamReader.

Comment: i'm a noob with c#, so posting it here to have an hand ... can you update your code to give me an hand?

Comment: See following example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?force_isolation=true&view=net-6.0

Comment: @jdweng check the update in my answer please. into the while